# composer runtime install Error - ENOENT

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am following the hyperledger composer tutorial of deploy business network to two organizations: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

I got a error message at step 11 and 12. It failed for both organizations. See the error message below:

[Fail Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1wfJ.png)

However I do see the files there, why does it say cannot find the file? See the screenshot below:
[ca.crt is in the directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSC9a.png)

Thank you for helping me in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `ls` command with the long filename in the screenshot to determine if the file is really there.  If it is not, then use the `find` command to find the exact path.

When you have found the exact path you will need to delete and re-create you business network cards for PeerAdmin before you continue.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I did use the ls command, and I am pretty sure the file is really there... I don't know why it can't find it.